# How to attach multiple UIDynamicItems to each other

Tags: ios, swift, uidynamicanimator

I am trying to implement circles attached to each other like in Apple's Music App via `UIDynamicAnimator`. I need to attach circles to each other and to view center. I was trying to implement this via `UIAttachmentBehavior`, but seems to it's not supporting multiple attachments. In result, circles overlaps on each other :)

```
let attachment = UIAttachmentBehavior(item: circle, attachedToAnchor: CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y))
attachment.length = 10
animator?.addBehavior(attachment)

let push = UIPushBehavior(items: [circle], mode: .continuous)

collision.addItem(circle)

animator?.addBehavior(push)
```

[image: Apple Music]
[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You want to attach all the circles to each other or you want circles as your first image?

Comment: Every behavior can have children.

Comment: @Darshan Patel as first image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the apple music genre picker thing uses `UIAttachmentBehavior` which is closer to attaching two views with a pole or a rope. But, it seems like the problem you're experiencing might be that all of the views are added at the same location which has the effect of placing them on top of each other and with the collision behavior causes them to be essentially be stuck together. One thing to do is to turn on `UIDynamicAnimator` debugging by calling `animator.setValue(true, forKey: "debugEnabled")`.

For recreating the above circle picker design, I would look into using `UIFieldBehavior.springField()`.

For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var animator: UIDynamicAnimator = {
        let animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: view)
        return animator
    }()
    lazy var collision: UICollisionBehavior = {
        let collision = UICollisionBehavior()
        collision.collisionMode = .items
        return collision
    }()
    lazy var behavior: UIDynamicItemBehavior = {
        let behavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior()
        behavior.allowsRotation = false
        behavior.elasticity = 0.5
        behavior.resistance = 5.0
        behavior.density = 0.01
        return behavior
    }()
    lazy var gravity: UIFieldBehavior = {
        let gravity = UIFieldBehavior.springField()
        gravity.strength = 0.008
        return gravity
    }()
    lazy var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didPan(_:)))
        return panGesture
    }()

    var snaps = [UISnapBehavior]()
    var circles = [CircleView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        animator.setValue(true, forKey: "debugEnabled")
        addCircles()
        addBehaviors()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        gravity.position = view.center
        snaps.forEach {
            $0.snapPoint = view.center
        }
    }

    func addCircles() {
        (1...30).forEach { index in
            let xIndex = index % 2
            let yIndex: Int = index / 3
            let circle = CircleView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: xIndex == 0 ? CGFloat.random(in: (-300.0 ... -100)) : CGFloat.random(in: (500 ... 800)), y: CGFloat(yIndex) * 200.0), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)))
            circle.backgroundColor = .red
            circle.text = "\(index)"
            circle.textAlignment = .center
            view.addSubview(circle)
            gravity.addItem(circle)
            collision.addItem(circle)
            behavior.addItem(circle)
            circles.append(circle)
        }
    }

    func addBehaviors() {
        animator.addBehavior(collision)
        animator.addBehavior(behavior)
        animator.addBehavior(gravity)
    }

    @objc
    private func didPan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: sender.view)
        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            animator.removeAllBehaviors()
            fallthrough
        case .changed:
            circles.forEach { $0.center = CGPoint(x: $0.center.x + translation.x, y: $0.center.y + translation.y)}
        case .possible, .cancelled, .failed:
            break
        case .ended:
            circles.forEach { $0.center = CGPoint(x: $0.center.x + translation.x, y: $0.center.y + translation.y)}
            addBehaviors()
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
        sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: sender.view)
    }
}

final class CircleView: UILabel {

    override var collisionBoundsType: UIDynamicItemCollisionBoundsType {
        return .ellipse
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height * 0.5
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

For more information I would watch [What's New in UIKit Dynamics and Visual Effects](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/229?time=546) from WWDC 2015

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have implemented almost everything :)